# Does startup costs show on the launch page's Avg CPU per Request

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I am testing a google app engine app.  I just deployed to the hosted server and opened my launch page a few times.  Because my app has no users, most times I load the page is a fresh launch for the app.  I look at my dashboard and see that my launch page has a very high Avg CPU per Request.  Is this because it is putting the costs of launching the entire app on the launch page or do I need to check my launch page for CPU culprits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - loading requests will simply take longer, and that'll be reflected in your averages. If you check the logs, there will be a message to that effect against any requests that required starting a new runtime.